# Telnet function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to telnet a device while getting IP address from a file but getting the attached error. I am attaching code from both files as images.[myswitches.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ5Y9.png)[test.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDHPZ.png)

```
    root@UbuntuDockerGuest-1:~# ./Test.py
    Enter your Telnet Username: david
    Password: 
    Configuring Switch 192.168.122.71

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./Test.py", line 15, in <module>
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 211, in __init__
        self.open(host, port, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
        self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
        for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Telnet is an ancient protocol that is almost certainly not running on `192.168.122.71`.

Comment: Hi Elliott
Thanks for feedback.
The telnet is running on destination machine and i can telnet the machine from the server running Python:
root@UbuntuDockerGuest-1:~# telnet 192.168.122.71
Trying 192.168.122.71...
Connected to 192.168.122.71.
Escape character is '^]'.

User Access Verification

Username: david
Password: 

S1#
S1#exit
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@UbuntuDockerGuest-1:~#

Comment: The error suggests you are using an invalid hostname, rather than an ip address. Without seeing your code it's impossible to tell. Please update your question to include your code (as text, not as a linked image).

Comment: Thanks.
I added strip() and it worked aftere removing whitespaces from IP addresses.